# SPFx CDN failed to load. 406 (Not Acceptable) Error

Tags: spfx, error, spfx-webparts, public-cdn

Web part is not loading, it's not able to load files from public SharePoint CDN.

[image]

Console error:

[image]

My findings on this issue:

1. I have checked with 3 users and one user is getting this error.
2. For me, some times web part was not loading but on the same time, it was loading in incognito mode.
3. We have 3 web parts on the page, for one user web part 2 was not loading and on next day web part 2 was loading and web part 3 was not loading.

Comment: Any solution found on this?